# Can I switch from Ubuntu to Mint using apt sources only?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, linux-mint

Is it possible to install Linux Mint 12 just by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` and putting Mint's repos there? I can copy them from the Live CD, of course.

I know a clean install would be better, but I've had it with Ubuntu.

My box has a lot of custom stuff that would take me a while to reconfigure after installing a new system, e.g. personal configuration files and scripts, Ruby Gems, Python pips, non-apt installations, custom compiled libraries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to get rid of unmaintained non-apt built software. It might become a showstopper upgrading to Mint. It needs some Debian stuff in addition to ubuntu too. Check in virtual machine.

Comment: thanks, I've already ran it on a VM and it looks like everything I have should work with it easily. I just thought of copying the apt sources file from mint to my ubuntu (12 is compliant with oneiric, so that's good) and see what happens. worst case - I'll do a clean reinstall.

Comment: This seems extremely vague and doesn't really answer the question. Could you expand?